# Alias to open git conflicts in textmate

Tags: git, bash, textmate, alias

How would I go about creating a bash alias that pipes any conflicting files from a git merge or git rebase into TextMate's mate command?

Comment: In other words, you want to use TextMate as your [git mergetool](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-mergetool)

Comment: I looked into that but I couldn't find a way to set mate as the mergetool's editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
textmate `git status | grep both | awk '{print $4}'`
```

where `textmate` is your command to run TextMate.

Comment: That's it! Just changed the command to `mate` which is the default way to launch TextMate from the command line. Otherwise it works great. Thanks!

Comment: You could make it more robust with `mate \`git status | grep 'both modified:' | awk '{print $4}'\``. This will prevent files like `*both*.x` to drop in accidentally.

Comment: Cool. Followed by a `git add \`git status | grep 'both modified:' | awk '{print $4}'\``